Deploy new field and Apex class WITH USER_MODE
I'm attempting to deploy a change that adds a new Custom Field and changes Apex code to include a query of this new field using "WITH USER_MODE." The deployment fails because the test class indicates the current user does not have access to the new field. The test does not include a RunAs statement, so the test class runs as the deploying user.
Shouldn't the deploying user automatically get security access to objects and fields?
The deployment works if the new field is deployed first, security on the field is granted to the deploying user, and then Apex changes are deployed.
Is this expected behavior when deploying a new field and deploying Apex Code that includes "WITH USER_MODE"?

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful.


Shouldn't the deploying user automatically get security access to objects and fields?

No. When deploying without including the relevant profile the deploying user won't have access to the field.
If you don't want to include the profile you can add a permissionset and create a PermissionSetAssignment in your test class. However, after creating the assignment you still should use System.runAs for the test to process the changed permissions correctly.
